# VSTS Chart Query by Parent/Feature

Tags: charts, azure-devops

I'm looking to create a nice dashboard in VSTS with a set of relevant charts for my collegues so they can keep track of things.

We have a project for keeping track of it operations tasks. In this project we've created different Features for different departments of the company.

Is there a way to filter the user stories by parent/feature so that I can make different charts for different departments? I've managed to create a "Work items and direct links" query that actually only outputs the User stories in one feature, but such queries can not be used in charts unfortunately.

Other workarounds would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Work Item Visualization extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.WorkItemVisualization) that you can check whether it meets your requirement (Can highlight specified work items).

Another way is that you can custom a dashboard widget or other extension to display the result: [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget).

There are many extension samples that may benefit you: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately they didn't get me forward, I can't afford spending time on my own widget.

Comment: How about the Work Item Visualization extension, you just need to install it, then use it directly.